# One ingress for two controllers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Suppose I have two Ingress Controllers handling `ingress-class` `nginx-internal` and `nginx-external`.
I want to expose a service with an Ingress, but I want it to be reachable on any of the controllers (ie. two Load Balancers).

I know a solution would be to create two ingresses with `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-internal` and `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-external` on each.

But :

- all the content of ingress would be duplicated (only the ingress.class annotation would be different)
- all helm charts I use does not allow to define multiple ingress (ex: keycloak, mercure, etc)

Do I have other choice than fork all charts I want to use just to allow me to declare multiple ingresses ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create an ingress controller for those helm charts if they do not support multiple ingresses?  Or is there any blocking point that requires you to run 2 ingress controllers?

Comment: Yeah I need to have two Ingress Controller because there is one public and one private (protected by GCP firewall with LoadBalancerSourceRange configured on the service).
I did not find better way to have a public and private access to service (with some resources not exposed on public access)